# Binding based on thread state

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF application with a few dozen user panels displayed in a listbox, each panel representing a task to execute. Within each panel there will be a 'Start' and 'Stop' button for controlling a thread.

Each panel includes a private background worker for execution and only one can be executing at a time since they access a shared resource. Therefore I want to disable the buttons in every panel that isn't running a task once a task begins in any panel and, of course, re-enable them when everything completes.

So I want to enable & disable based on 2 properties:
1. Whether the private background worker instance variable is null
2. Whether a public static object has a lock (obtained using Monitor.Enter or lock)

I would like to enable/disable the buttons based on the following logic:

'Start' button:
- enabled if public object is not locked (means no threads are running), else disabled (at least one thread, possibly the one from this class, is running)

'Stop' button
- Enabled if private background worker is not null (thread from this class is starting/running), else disabled (no applicable threads to stop)

When a thread starts it will obtain a lock on the shared object and initialize the local background worker which will enable the single stop button and disable all other start buttons.

I'm pretty new to WPF and am looking into data binding. I could probably figure out how to bind to the background worker == or != null but I'm not sure about how to test whether a lock exists on an object and how to bind to that.

Examples:
Here is some sample code following up on answers provided below

Create a userpanel with two buttons (no bindings implemented for stop button)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button Margin="2" x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" Click="btnStart_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding CanCommandsExecute}"/>
<Button Margin="2" x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Place multiple instances of this into a window

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<wpfsample:TestControl/>
<wpfsample:TestControl/>
<wpfsample:TestControl/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the codebehind for TestControl

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static bool IsLocked = false;
    private static object threadlock = new object();
    private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _canCommandsExecute = true;
    public bool CanCommandsExecute { 
        get { return _canCommandsExecute && (!IsLocked); } 
        set { _canCommandsExecute = value; OnPropertyChanged("CanCommandsExecute"); } }

    public TestControl()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(threadlock);
        try
        {
            IsLocked = true;
            this.CanCommandsExecute = false;
            _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            _worker.DoWork += (x, y) => { Thread.Sleep(5000); };
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkComplete;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch { Monitor.Exit(threadlock); }
    }

    private void WorkComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsLocked = false;
        this.CanCommandsExecute = true;
        Monitor.Exit(threadlock);
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }            
    }

}
```

This partially solves the question. When you hit start it disables the button and runs a background task. It does so using a WPF binding as requested as well.

The outstanding question is how to make ALL the start buttons disable instead of just one. I'm getting a lock on a static object (which isn't working right at the moment, looking into that)

Hopefully this example helps

Comment: Without giving a complete answer, it sounds like you need to bind to the object using a data converter.  This will allow you to do whatever checks you need in code instead of xaml. Possibly with multibinding.

Comment: If the requirement is such that no other task can be executed until the current task completes, why are you using threading at all, out of curiosity?  Am I missing something?  What you've laid out sounds like textbook synchronous operation - user can perform one of a selection of tasks, but one at a time...

Comment: @Erik I'm using threading because the tasks that start are long running processes, not just a second or two but in some cases up to a half hour and I don't want them running in the UI thread. There are also other things you can do in the UI while a task is running (such as review the results of another previously completed task, etc).

Comment: Gotcha -- makes sense.  Given what you said there and your comment about being new to WPF, I posted a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what your binding structure is (code behind, view models, etc), I would suggest that you forget about figuring out how to make the GUI/WPF understand your underlying object model and focus on making your code easy to use from the XAML.

To wit, don't spend time figuring out how to bind XAML to whether or not something is null and whether or not something else is locked.  Instead, expose a property from your binding target that resolves these into what the object wants.

Rachel's RelayCommand (or perhaps a DelegateCommand) is a good idea, as that is a nice way to work with buttons.  However, if you're new to WPF, that might be a little much to start with, in terms of really understanding what's going on.

Let's say that your buttons bind to some click event that is handled in your code behind:

```
public void ButtonClickHandler(/*Arguments elided*/)
{
    //Start the appropriate thread
}
```

Now, if you make this piece of code behind the source of your binding:

```
public class MyPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private bool _canCommandsExecute;
    public bool CanCommandsExecute { get { return _canCommandsExecute; } set { _canCommandsExecute = value; RaisePropertyChanged("CanCommandsExecute"); } }

    public MyPage()
    {
         DataContext = this;
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ButtonClickHandler(/*Arguments elided*/)
    {
         CanExecute = false;
         //Pseudocode: Thread.OnCompleted += (sender, completeargs) => CanExecute = true;
         //Start the appropriate thread
    }
}
```

Your buttons in XAML then bind to the boolean property here for their IsEnabled properties, which will be set to false when you start a task and then set back to true when the task completes.  The property setter will trigger PropertyChanged for the GUI, which will update the buttons back to enabled.

To be clear, this is something that is conceptually easy to understand if you're new to the framework, but not the best way to do it, in my opinion.  It's a stepping stone to the best way to do it.  Once you understand what's going on here, you can look into using View Models for binding and into looking at binding buttons to RelayCommands or DelegateCommands on the view model, instead of using event handlers and button IsEnabled.  That was my experience, anyway, when learning WPF.  ViewModels/Commands are elegant, but it's easier to understand the benefits of them and why they're often preferable once you've done it the easier-to-understand, code-behind way first.

Comment: I'm going to assume that line 'CanExecute = false' should be 'CanCommandsExecute=false' to trigger the OnPropertyChanged event. I agree with what you are saying, keep it simple. Rachel definitely knows what she is talking about, and I will read up on that, but it is a lot to take in at the moment. Binding to a single property is easier but it would be my Testcase class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, which is the UserPanel containing the Start button. This is fine for enabling/disabling the start/stop button in  this 1 panel but not all the others in other classes. Thats where I got stuck

Comment: The requirement I have is that (given your example) when ButtonClickHandler sets CanCommandsExecute=false every other instance of this class would also be false. The event handler is an instance method and it could set a static bool IsLocked, or something, in the testcase class but the problem is how to then force property change notification on every instance. These UserPanels are working independently of one another with only the shared object lock. Would something like having each instance object  handle an OnLockChange event defined in the base class work? Raise the event when togglinglock

Comment: So, you have a collection in XAML bound to a collection of objects.  Fair enough.  Is there somewhere in the code (not XAML) that you have a reference to all objects in the collection?  If so, you can listen to each one's CanCommandsExecute property changed, and set the value in the others (though you should put a guard only to fire the notification if the value has changed if you do that to prevent stack overflow).  

(And yes, I meant to set CanCommandsExecute -- I was typing it freehand :o )

Comment: Oh, I just saw your updates to the original post with code.  So, one thing you could do to get it working is to name the controls:<wpfsample:TestControl x:Name="Control1"/>  Then, in the code behind for that class, you'd be able to listen for their property changed and go through setting the others.  Please note, that is something that will work -- not the most elegant thing you can do by any stretch, but I'm a believer in getting it working than refining.  Once that's working for you, I suggest looking into the concept of View Models for binding rather than code-behind.

Comment: Technically I DO have a collection of all these but I want them to work independently. I agree with you getting it working then refine and on that note I could set the enabled properly entirely in the codebehind. I'm trying to learn how to do it without that though. The design is that they all work independently (with the exception that they can't access a shared resource while executing). I posted some source code. The lock doesn't work right yet (looking into it, new to threading as well, geez!) but you can see the general idea.

Comment: As an aside, the concept of having them work independently is sort of a non-starter as soon as you have each instance operate on a static variable of the class.  Since they all know about that variable, they are, ipso facto, no longer independent.  But, I digress.  I think you're on the right track not wanting to name controls defined in XAML And manipulate them from code behind.  That is a good practice indeed.  As to your specific situation...

Comment: I would consider modifying your design to move the logic out of the Test Control code behind and into a new class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged (call it TestControlViewModel).  Now, on the parent class/control containing these guys, you can have a property -- an ObservableCollection<TestControlViewModel>, that the XAML binds to for the collection.  You would then create the TestControlViewModel objects in the code-behind of that class.  Now, your code knows about the objects and can manage their state, but you don't have to declare and name them in XAML.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably bind my button to a `RelayCommand` in the ViewModel, which has it's `CanExecute` bound to an `CanExecute` flag.

I would also use an event system such as PRISM's `EventAggregator` to broadcast messages about if a thread has started or not, and the individual items would subscribe to these items and set the `CanExecute` flag based on this.

Since the Button's `Command` property would be bound to a `RelayCommand`, they will be automatically enabled/disabled when the CanExecute parameter would evaluate to false.

Here's an example. I left out some parts of it to try and keep the code limited to only the relevant bits.

```
public class SomeBaseClass()
{
    Public SomeBaseClass(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ThreadStartedEvent>().Subscribe(DisableCanExecute);
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<ThreadStoppedEvent>().Subscribe(EnableCanExecute);
    }

    private bool _canExecute;
    private ICommand _startCommand;
    private ICommand _endCommand;

    public ICommand StartCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_startCommand== null)
            {
                _startCommand= new RelayCommand(
                    param => StartThread(),
                    param => this.BackgroundWorker != null && this.CanExecute
                );
            }
            return _startCommand;
        }
    }

    public ICommand EndCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_endCommand== null)
            {
                _endCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => StopThread(),
                    param => this.IsRunning == true
                );
            }
            return _endCommand;
        }
    }

    public void DisableCanExecute(ThreadStartedEvent e)
    {
       CanExecute = false;
    }

    public void EnableCanExecute(ThreadStoppedEvent e)
    {
       CanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

I actually don't like the syntax to PRISM's `EventAggregator` because I don't like to pass the event aggregator around to my ViewModels, so usually use a helper class which makes it static. The code for that can be found [here](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/)

I also usually use [MVVM Light's](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) version of `RelayCommand`, or you can make your own. I could also use PRISM's `DelegateCommand`, although that one doesn't automatically re-run `CanExecute()` when parameters change. The basic definition of a `RelayCommand` looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A command whose sole purpose is to relay its functionality to other
/// objects by invoking delegates. The default return value for the
/// CanExecute method is 'true'.
/// </summary>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this would work when there are multiple different commands that have to be executed. So if I have 20 instances of my class (derived from UserPanel) that each contains a Start & Stop button each class would have a RelayCommand for the work it has to do right? I could bind to CanExecute for that specific relay command but I need to bind to CanExecute for each and every instance of the class as only one can really execute at a time. Or, in the RelayCommand thats where it checks for the shared lock perhaps so there is only ever a single binding?

Comment: @Eric I would have base class which defines the Commands, and inherit that functionality so you wouldn't be re-writing it 20 times. The most you'd have to do is overwrite the Start/Stop methods in each class to run your processes. And if you're using a static object as a lock, you should be able to access it from all the classes. And a RelayCommand will re-evaluate it's CanExecute method if any of the CanExecute parameters change, so you should be able to get it automatically enabling/disabling buttons if they're available or not.

Comment: Each class represents a test to run and the base class defines once the method for execution so that is defined once, and I could put the RelayCommand in the base class as well. What changes in each instance is the test name, description, path to a file, etc - properties that are displayed but don't change the behavior of how a test executes. The static lock object will be accessible from all instances but handling the change event is where I'm confused. When one object gets/releases the lock 'CanExecute' would have to be re-evaluated for every other instance.

Comment: (Continued) - You say that CanExecute will reevaluate if any of its parameters change but would simply acquiring / releasing a lock on a static object result in a change that would force reevaluation? I'm not sure if a lock actually changes anything. If it doesn't count as a change then I'd need a second parameter such as static bool IsLocked that I toggle within the Monitor codeblock in order to force a real change. Thats how I'm seeing it conceptually, I haven't used a RelayCommand before so if the concept makes sense I'll research it more specifically and try a mock-up

Comment: @Eric Personally I'd use something like PRISM's `EventAggregator`, and broadcast a message when a thread starts or stops. Then your individual classes could subscribe to stop/start messages and update their `CanExecute` or not based on that.

Comment: Okay. You've given me a lot of things to read up on. At this point I think I have some research to do :)

I'll return to this question later after I've learned a little bit more and will either update it with new information or mark it answered. Thanks for pointing me in any direction, I have a good place to start now.

Comment: @Eric I actually updated my answer to show an example using the `EventAggregator`. I am much more comfortable working with that then I am with static locks, but you could probably still use static locks if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to answer my own questions but I had a specific scenario I was trying to get.

1. Each instance of a class was a user panel containing start & stop buttons
2. There would be multiple instances on the screen at any given time
3. When any one had clicked start every other start button would be disabled until the task had finished.

@Erik - Good suggestions posted here but it involved something external (a wrapper class perhaps) to manage all the instances. My goal is for all the instances to work independently of one another. It is true that there is some interdependency but this exists within the class's static members, so the class by itself still remains independent.

@Rachel - This was a bit over my head for now but I'm going to try to make a solution using your suggestions as I learn more about WPF.

Thank you both for the suggestions.

---

This solution uses the XAML from the example in my question (with the classname changed to Testcase) but all the work is done in code behind. There are no databindings.

There are class static events handled in each class. If any instance starts or stops each class handles this event and enables/disables its own buttons. This keeps all the logic within the class itself without a wrapper class.

This uses a background worker for threading which lacks an abort method, so it has to poll for cancel. There are better approaches but since this was a UI synchronization question and not a threading question I left it simple for an example.

```
public partial class Testcase : UserControl
{

    public static event EventHandler TestStarted;
    public static event EventHandler TestStopped;
    private static object lockobject = new object();

    private BackgroundWorker _worker;

    public Testcase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Register private event handlers with public static events
        Testcase.TestStarted += this.OnTestStart;
        Testcase.TestStopped += this.OnTestStop;

        //Set the default button states (start = enabled, stop = disabled)
        //Could be done in XAML, done here for clarity
        btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
        btnStop.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void OnTestStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButtonStatus(sender, true);
    }

    private void OnTestStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButtonStatus(sender, false);
    }

    private void UpdateButtonStatus(object eventCaller, bool testStarted)
    {
        Testcase testcase;
        if ((eventCaller is Testcase) && (eventCaller != null))
            testcase = (Testcase)eventCaller;
        else
            return;

        btnStart.IsEnabled = !testStarted;
        btnStop.IsEnabled = (eventCaller == this) && testStarted;
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (Testcase.lockobject)
        {
            try
            {
                //Raise the event starting the test while still in the UI thread
                TestStarted(this, new EventArgs());

                //Use a background worker to execute the test in a second thread
                _worker = new BackgroundWorker() { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = true };                    
                _worker.DoWork += (x, y) => 
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <=50; i++)
                        {
                            if (_worker.CancellationPending)
                            {
                                y.Cancel = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            //Simulate work
                            Thread.Sleep(100); 
                        }                      
                    };
                _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkComplete;
                _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Ignore handling the error for the POC but raise the stopped event
                TestStopped(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    private void WorkComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestStopped(this,new EventArgs());
    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Terminate the background worker
        _worker.CancelAsync();
    }




}
```